# Spring Bean validation with custom validator

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have implemented a custom size validation in order to add "errorCode" to a validation error.

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { StringLengthValidator.class })
public @interface StringLength {

    String message() default "Size must be between {min} and {max}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    long min() default 0L;

    long max();

    String errorCode() default "";

}
```

I have annotated a field in my DTO with the following:

```
@StringLength(min = 5, max = 400, errorCode = "1000001")
```

In the `@RestControllerAdvice` I added the following:

```
@ExceptionHandler({WebExchangeBindException.class})
Mono<ResponseEntity<...>> webExchangeBindException(WebExchangeBindException exception, ServerHttpRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

How can I get the errorCode of the original annotation, in order to add that to my response?

I have found that `exception.getFieldError().getArguments()` contains an array with the the value I want wrapped in a `SpringValidatorAdapter.ResolvableAttribute` but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with was to inject a `javax.validation.Validator` into the `@RestControllerAdvice` Then use the following `@ExceptionHandler` to get the "errorCode" value of the validation annotation.

```
@ExceptionHandler({WebExchangeBindException.class})
Mono<ResponseEntity<...>> webExchangeBindException(WebExchangeBindException exception, ServerHttpRequest request) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(exception.getTarget());
    violations.stream()
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(violation -> /*Assign error here */ ... violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes().get("errorCode"));
    return ...;
}
```

This works, but I feel there should be a better way to do this.